# How to submit a HTML form(from android web view) when the user presses the ENTER key on the soft keyboard

Tags: android, html, post, webview

I am showing a simple HTML edit box inside an Android webview. User enters some input through the Android standard IME (or any soft IME to that matter) and presses ENTER key. Expectation is once user presses the ENTER key, the HTML page should be notified that it can post the data to the server.

Right now I am not able to tell this to the HTML page. So user has to click somewhere on the screen, upon which the POST happens.

My question is how can i notify the webview (finally the HTML page) to POST data to server on soft key ENTER press

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called as [Jockeyjs](https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs) it can be used to communicate between native and the Webview.
you can get keypress event from native and pass it to webview. Or else if you can use jquery on your html you can do some thing like this

```
$( "#inputbox" ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
    if(event.which ==13)  //13 is for enterkey
     {
      $("#form").submit();
     }
 });
```